# Select Case with Radio Buttons - Having trouble w/ Null Value

Tags: ms-access, vba

Having a bit of trouble. I have a simple situation: 2 Radio buttons, Accept or Reject. Instead of doing IF statements I feel an obligation to do Select statements.

As I walk through my code, it gets to the Case rdbApprove.Value and complains that the value is null. I figure it isn't true, thus it should pass to the next Case. Nope - it hangs on the fact that it is null.

In an effort to try and get rid of the null value I tried the NZ(rdbApprove.Value, False) to try and tell it that it was false but that still isn't working.

```
Select Case True
    Case rdbApprove.Value

    Case rdbReject.Value

    Case Else
        MsgBox "ERROR!"

End Select
```

Comment: Why do you 'feel an obligation to do Select statements'? Your code looks a little weird to me - usually in a `Select Case` the selected-for value is a runtime-determined one and the possible options are constants; your code has things the other way round though. Personally I'd just just a simple `If` statement in your situation.

Comment: Shouldn't a radio button either be on or off, and shouldn't you only care about if the approve button is on?  So, what about saying `if (rdbApprove) then blahblah end if`

Answer (score 3):

The usual way this is done is to include your radio buttons in an option group.  Then your code can reference the option group `.Value`.

My form includes an option group named *Frame15* which includes an "Approve" radio button whose *Option Value* is 1, and a "Reject" button whose *Option Value* is 2.

I also added a command button to inspect the option group `.Value`.  Here is its click event procedure.

```vb
Private Sub cmdOptionValue_Click()
    Dim strPrompt As String
    Select Case Me.Frame15.value
    Case 1
        strPrompt = "approved"
    Case 2
        strPrompt = "rejected"
    Case Else
        If IsNull(Me.Frame15.value) Then
            strPrompt = "Null"
        Else
            strPrompt = "this should not happen"
        End If
    End Select
    MsgBox strPrompt
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 because your answer is correct, but with a rep of 49K+ I would expect something better than "Frame15".  C'mon, man!  ;o)

Comment: Woot!  You're right; I wouldn't do that "for real". ;-)